# How to create simple dismemberment in Unreal Engine 4

Tags: game-physics, unreal-engine4, unreal-blueprint

So basically, I'm trying to create really simple dismemberment in UE4, by either breaking or separating a bone from a skeletal mesh. Currently, I'm using version 4.21.2, and I can't find any threads that are up to date.

I've viewed multiple threads, like https://forums.unrealengine.com/community/community-content-tools-and-tutorials/63828-tutorial-preview-gore-mesh-dismemberment-tutorial?92161-Tutorial-Preview-Gore-Mesh-amp-Dismemberment-Tutorial=, but they are all for previous versions of UE4, and the plugins don't work. I've also tried the "Break Constraint" node  ([Blueprint Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFDj8.png)), but it just makes the limbs stretch far away from each other. I have no knowledge of C++ and I would like to do it in only blueprints.

What should happen is that the limbs just fall off and become separate bodies, but instead the become all stretchy (Results: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cqWv4.jpg). Is there another way to do this? Am I using the wrong nodes?
Thanks in advance, 12YOK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it becomes stretchy is that you're using a single skeletal mesh. Vertexes in that mesh are connected and they will follow their bone, even if you detach bones in the hierarchy.

To make something like this work, you will need to have 2 separate skeletal meshes on each side of the breaking joint. Each of them will have the same skeleton as your base character skeleton.

Comment: Can I please have visual clarification on how to do this? I am relatively new to Unreal Engine 4, and I do know a little blender, but that's about it.